# Not *item_geofunc.cc.o* compiled when compiling the mysql from the 512mb

Tags: mysql, linux, compilation

> Summary.  Not the ***item_geofunc.cc.o*** compiled when compiling the mysql from the 512
>   memory.

I am compiling a mysql.
The computer's following specifications, it has been working in virtualbox.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo

CPU
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2435M CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 7
cpu MHz     : 2394.542
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4789.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

and memory is

```
cat /proc/meminfo

MemTotal:         500252 kB
MemFree:          337428 kB
MemAvailable:     445040 kB
Buffers:           23844 kB
Cached:            80984 kB
SwapCached:         1968 kB
Active:            82352 kB
Inactive:          32276 kB
Active(anon):       4448 kB
Inactive(anon):     8460 kB
Active(file):      77904 kB
Inactive(file):    23816 kB
Unevictable:        3660 kB
Mlocked:            3660 kB
SwapTotal:        522236 kB
SwapFree:         515892 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         12212 kB
Mapped:             9192 kB
Shmem:               684 kB
Slab:              29508 kB
SReclaimable:      16428 kB
SUnreclaim:        13080 kB
KernelStack:        1856 kB
PageTables:         2292 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      772360 kB
Committed_AS:     137340 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       47040 kB
DirectMap2M:      477184 kB
```

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 and installed to add these packages.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install bison
```

After downloading the files from the mysql site,

```
http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.12.tar.gz
```

I have a problem with the following options during compilation.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/server/mysql-5.7.12 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/home/server/repository/mysql-5.7.12 -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=/home/download/mysql-boost/mysql-5.7.12/boost_1_59_0/boost -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DWITH_EXTRA_CHARSETS=all -DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=TRUE -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=TRUE -DINSTALL_LAYOUT=STANDALONE -DWITH_ZLIB=bundled -DWITH_SSL=bundled -DENABLED_PROFILING=ON -DMYSQL_MAINTAINER_MODE=OFF -DWITH_DEBUG=OFF -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/tmp/mysql.sock -DMYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306
```

But it stops at **item_geofunc.cc.o**. No error. Not even after a long time to compile.

```
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message_field.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_primitive_field.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_service.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_string_field.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_context.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum_field.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protoclib.dir/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_extension.cc.o

....

[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/filesort.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/filesort_utils.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/aggregate_check.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/geometry_rtree.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/gstream.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/handler.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/hostname.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/init.cc.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/item.cc.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/item_buff.cc.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/item_cmpfunc.cc.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/item_create.cc.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/item_func.cc.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/item_geofunc.cc.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this issue while compiling on a 512 VPS also. I upgraded it to 4GB and the issue was resolved.